# Time dependency of the phase of a single photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, photons

I am wondering if a wave packet of a single photon in the time domaine
$$
\psi(t)=|\psi(t)|\; \text e^{\text i \varphi(t)}
$$
can have a different $t$ dependence in phase than the simple phase $\varphi(t)=\omega_0 t$ ?

The big theoretical advantage of such a simple phase is that the fourier transormation of $\psi$ has a mean value of $\omega_0$ so we call $\omega_0$ the mean frequency of the photon.

But what is with with other $t$ dependencies like $\varphi(t) \sim t^3$ or crazy things like $\varphi(t) \sim \sin(t^5)$... ?

Or is $\varphi(t)=\omega_0 t$ the best approximation for all possible photons in nature?

Comment: Is this a 1d or a 3d photon vs time? One can argue that there are only two quantum 'states' (left and right circular), as opposed to an infinity of linear directions. The real world extra dimensions (3d, amazing) gives extra degrees of freedom..

Answer (score 2):

The other big advantage of $\omega_0 t$ is that it is the time dependence of energy eigenstates.  Other time dependencies can be constructed, but they won't have such nice properties as $E=h\nu$, etc.

The usual definition of a "photon" has it being an energy eigenstate, so in a sense the frequency must be fixed by definition.  Other electromagnetic wave states exist, but we don't call them photon states.

Comment: Every real photon has a bandwidth greater than zero. A very narrow photon in the time domaine has a very broad bandwidth thus it can not have a fixed frequency. I am not talking abou a Photon as a Fock state but of a electromagnetic pulse. I still don't see why the phase $\varphi(t)$ can't have any crazy dependency on $t$.

Comment: Semantics, I guess.  To me a photon is a single excitation of a single mode of an EM field.  I've seen presentations of wave packets that might be construed as particles, but I don't call them photons.  Others may differ.

Comment: Ok, maybe we can go a bit more to the notion of a pulse. For example in this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrashort_pulse) you can see a pulse which can not have a simple phase $\omega_0 t$. My question is still open: Am I free to choose any function?